# How to commit new project in the branch using cvs and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cvs

How to commit a newly created project in branch. I tried it, but it is getting committed in HEAD. Please help me

Comment: people are still using CVS? is it the 1990s all over again?

Comment: Don't do that! you might lost your change when you swtich to Another Branch but the the project does not exist in the branch you want swtich to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Team > Switch to Another Branch or Version